# In React how would I disable onSubmit call for some text fields and not others?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `dataModal` that has two text boxes, a searchable data table, and a submit button. The `Name` and `Date` text boxes need to be filled out manually, and the dataTable is a component that can be searched via it's own text boxes to narrow down what data needs to be entered.

The problem that I am facing is when searching the data table using the text input fields pressing enter causes the form to submit. This is likely happening because the data table is in the form that the submit button is in.

Is there a way to have the text fields in the dataTable not submit the form while retaining the ability to submit the form when pressing enter in the name or date form?

```
const dataModal = (props) => {

  const { data, save, close } = props;
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [date, setDate] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    save(name, date); // DB Call from parent
    close(); // Closes the modal
  }

  return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <customInput 
      name="NameTextField"
      captureInput={(value) => {setName(value)}}
    /> // Custom text box component

    <customInput
      name="DateTextField"
      captureInput={(value) => {setDate(value)}}
    />  // Custom text box component

    <searchableDataTable
      name="SearchableDataTable"
      data=data
    /> // Data Table with customInputs build the same as above that are used for filtering the data table

    <Button type="submit" /> // Submission button
  </form> 
  )
}
```

Moving the data table below the `form` tabs works, but it causes "ugly" rendering in which the submit button is in the middle of the modal, and not at the bottom. This is the fallback solution if I'm unable to figure this out.

Comment: Your form submits because it has a submit button. Change that to a `button` type and manually submit the form when you want to.

Comment: Correct, the solution I'm looking for is one where it's possible to retain the functionality to press enter and submit the form from the top two text fields if at all possible.

Comment: I suppose you'd add a keydown handler on those, then.

Comment: Keydown handler worked perfectly. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume you pick "Name" to be required (also assuming everything works in your custominput), you could try this:

```
const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState();

const isValid = (value) => {
    // return true or false
}
...
<customInput 
    name="NameTextField"
    captureInput={(value) => {
        setName(value)
        setButtonState(isValid(value))
    }}
/>
...
<Button {buttonState ? disabled="disabled" : ""} />
```

Please note isherwood's comment also.